# Фильтр таксономии с кастомным типом поста в wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Нашел вот такой код:

php:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

  wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ),
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      )
  );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);

$result = array();

function ajax_filter_get_posts( $taxonomy ) {

  if( !isset( $_POST['afp_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['afp_nonce'], 'afp_nonce' ) )
    die('Permission denied');

  $taxonomy = $_POST['taxonomy'];

  $args = array(
    'tag'            => $taxonomy,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );

  if( !$taxonomy ) {
    unset( $args['tag'] );
  }

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $result['response'][] = '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'. get_the_title().'</a></h2>' . get_the_excerpt();
    $result['status']     = 'success';

  endwhile; else:
    $result['response'] = '<h2>No posts found</h2>';
    $result['status']   = '404';
  endif;

  $result = json_encode($result);
  echo $result;

  die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');
```

script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tax-filter').click( function(event) {

        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        var selecetd_taxonomy = $(this).attr('title');

        $('.tagged-posts').fadeOut();

        data = {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            afp_nonce: afp_vars.afp_nonce,
            taxonomy: selecetd_taxonomy,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: afp_vars.afp_ajax_url,
            data: data,
            success: function( data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest ) {

                $('.tagged-posts').html( data.response );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            },
            error: function( MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                $('.tagged-posts').html( 'No posts found' );
                $('.tagged-posts').fadeIn();
            }
        })

    });
});
```

В шаблоне ссылки таксономии `"product-brand"` имеют `class="tax-filter"`, а в архивах типа поста `"product"` установлен код: `<div class="tagged-posts"><?php ajax_filter_posts_scripts(); ?></div>`. После установки в коде в шаблоне появляется `permission denied` и все.

Далее код не выполняется, блокируя все, что прописано после, и не работает сам скрипт. Я понимаю, что срабатывает `die()` из-за невалидации `nonce`, но не пойму, почему не проходит валидация.

Comment: так вы этот `nonce`-то сгенерировали?

Comment: а разве в php при подключении скрипов это не происходит?

Comment: По логике вашего скрипта - происходит. У меня ваш пример заработал в части сравнения `nonce` (сократила js-часть до отправки ключа и получения ответа).

Comment: А для чего нужна эта строка `<div class="tagged-posts"><?php ajax_filter_posts_scripts(); ?></div>`? Подключение скриптов функцией `ajax_filter_posts_scripts()` должно происходить при выполнении `wp_head()` в шапке сайта.

Comment: Со скриптом, вроде, все нормально, он там и подключается. Вышеупомянутая строка выводит данные (именно в блоке с классом `tagged-posts`). Но у меня проблема с nonce с кастомным типом поста и таксономией.

Comment: @alenkins, немного поковыряв код пришел к выводу, что действительно натупил с `ajax_filter_posts_scripts()`. Поставил `<div class="tagged-posts"></div>` и действительно по нажатию появляются нужные посты, но остался вопрос вот в чем: когда я обновляю страницу, она пустая. Только после выбора таксономии появляются посты. Как оформить шаблон, чтобы при заходе по ссылке напр. `domen/tax_name/tax` - отображались существующие этой таксономии посты, а после выбора другой, они просто менялись на новые?

Comment: Ну вариантов-то два: либо при загрузке страницы сразу отправляйте post-запрос со всеми необходимыми параметрами, либо на стороне сервера в файле, отвечающем за вывод записей на целевой странице вызывайте функцию `ajax_filter_get_posts()`, передавая ей в параметре имя таксономии