# Не работает wp_ajax_nopriv

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

подключил код [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489618/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-wordpress), подключив поддержку AJAX с помощью `wp_localize_script`:

```
function ajax_filter_posts_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('afp_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', false, null, false);
  wp_enqueue_script('afp_script');

  wp_localize_script( 'afp_script', 'afp_vars', array(
        'afp_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'afp_nonce' ),
        'afp_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      )
  );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_filter_posts_scripts', 100);
```

Когда я залогинен, все работает без проблем. Как только выхожу иp аккаунта - скрипт не обрабатывает данные, при все скрипты подключаются.
Пробовал варианты: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748819/wordpress-wp-ajax-nopriv-not-working) и [ссылка](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajax-returns-whole-page-content-when-user-is-not-logged-in-wordpress).

Comment: Строку `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'ajax_filter_get_posts');` не удалили?

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро, это первое, что я проверил ))

Comment: Тем не менее, если в консоли ошибок нет, по всей видимости не отрабатывает именно данный хук.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалась проблема со стороны хостинга. Отключил дополнительную защиту файлов со стороны сервера - получилось. Ответ нашел тут: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559947/cross-origin-authorization-header-with-jquery-ajax).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/59345)

Comment: @Streletz, я же вроде написал, что проблема была с дополнительной блокировкой файлов со стороны хостинга/сервера для защиты от ботов.

Comment: То, что Вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос это прекрасно! Однако лучше всё-таки, по возможности, раскрывать здесь хотя бы общую суть. В Вашем случае общая суть раскрыта по ссылке. Поэтому, если со страницей по ссылке что-то случится, другим людям, которые будут читать Ваш ответ будет сложно понять в чём конкретно состоит проблема и её решение. Ничего личного. Просто на будущее..